# How to add additional output info from code to robotframework *.html report

Tags: python, robotframework

in teardown() method i have a dictionary with key and value and i need to add this data in robot *.html report BUT each KEY-VALUE pair should be as separate keyword with KEY in header and VALUE in body.

how can i do it?

Comment: Could you show how you want it to look? It's not quite clear. What do you call "podcast"?

Comment: @Psytho , it's field look like fild "SUITE", i.e. field that is opening by click on plus ("+")

Comment: Do you need the KEY printed in **bold** as all keywords are or in normal text as arguments?

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot answer an "OR"-question with "yes". It would be nice WHAT?

Comment: @Psytho , yes it would be nice if KEY will be in **bold**

Comment: It's not possible because only keyword are printed in bold. There is a workaround using for-loop and `Run Keyword` but it still wouldn't look as you want it and wouldn't worth efforts anyway. What are you trying to achieve and why just printing the dictionary does not satisfy your needs? PS. A _podcast_ is a (periodical) digital audio recording which you can download, and not what you call it.

Answer (score 0):

I find decision as follow:

```
from robot.api import logger

def teardown(self):
    try:
        self.myDict = self._myMethod(self.firstNum, self.secondNum)
        for key, value in self.myDict.iteritems():
            logger.info('<br/><b><u>' + key + '</u></b><br/>', html=True)
            logger.info(value)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Log Diff detection failed. Exception: {}'.format(e.message))
```

it's looks:
- TEARDOWN
--- KEYWORD
--- *date-time* INFO ***key***
--- *date-time* INFO *value*